# Storing records in a dropdownlist from DB without using LINQ Data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a website for dance academy where Users can register and add/drop dance classes.

In the web page to drop a particular dance, for a particular user, the dropdown displays her registered dances.

Now I want to delete one of the dances from the list.

So i'll remove the row from the table and also from the dropdownlist. The problem is that every time the item with the lowest ID (index) is getting deleted, no matter which one the user selects.

I think I am storing the DataTextField and DataValueField for the dropdown incorrectly. Can someone please help me out?
The code is:

```
private void PopulateDanceDropDown()
        {



            var registereddanceList = from dd in context.DANCER_AND_DANCE
                                        where dd.UserId == dancerId
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            Text = dd.DanceName,
                                             Value = dd.DanceId
                                        };

            dances.DataSource = registereddanceList;
            dances.DataTextField = "Text";
            dances.DataValueField = "Value";
            dances.DataBind();

        }

        protected void dropthedance(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            String strDataValueField = dances.SelectedItem.Value;            
            int danceIDFromDropDown = Convert.ToInt32(strDataValueField);
            var dancer_dance = from dd in context.DANCER_AND_DANCE
                               where dd.DanceId == danceIDFromDropDown
                               select dd;



            foreach (var dndd in dancer_dance)
            {
                context.DANCER_AND_DANCE.DeleteOnSubmit(dndd);

            }

            try
            {
                context.SubmitChanges();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            PopulateDanceDropDown();

        }


<asp:DropDownList ID = "dances" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="dropDance" runat="server" OnClick="dropthedance" Text="Drop Class" BackColor="Maroon" ForeColor="#FFCC99"/>
```

Comment: Is `context` the same instance in both pieces of code? And what do you mean by _without using LINQ Data source_ in your title? Is that a requirement, is that where it fails? Your code looks like it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

As your question says you want to access records without storing it in Linq.

So below one could be an alternative for you.

First store all the data from Database to, lets say `List<NameIDPair>`

Heres what `NameIDPair` could be:

```
class NameIDPair 
{
public NameIDPair(){}
public string NameValue{get;set;}
public string IDValue{get;set;}
}
```

Then populate  drop down list as follows:

```
List<NameIDPair> storeInMe = From Database
foreach(NameIDPair pair in storeInMe )
{
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Value = pair.IDValue;
item.Text = pair.NameValue;
ddldancesList.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Then for droppingTheDance, you can call the delete stored procedure to delete the same...

Hope this helps...